# Issue in adding sub-apps in settings.py file

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am unable to add my sub apps like category, user in settings.py. It was working fine but don't know what mistake I have done. Please help. I'm not able to progress from here.
Please create a model and get that model to admin panel.
[Link to github](https://github.com/ASHUaman/ecom)

Comment: Can you share the errors?

Comment: did you register the models in the admin file ?

Comment: Add a blank file inside `ecommerce/api/category/` directory named `__init__.py`

Answer (score 0):

in the admin.py within your "api" folder register the created models so as to display it in the admin panel,

api: **admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import (model created in the models.py)
# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(model created in the models.py)
```

link to official documentation :

[Admin site Official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/)

Comment: https://github.com/ASHUaman/ecommerce   sir done. but still can't add in installed apps

Comment: Cant see any changes in admin.py file

Comment: also upload your models too

Comment: Thanks for your valuable support. Models and serialize updated. but I can't add any other subapp in the settings.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/16Dmgy1tamrsap0L8wMLEcfFECQwe35OI?usp=sharing

Comment: your admin.py still is empty. and what do you mean by cant add subapp in settings ?? is it that you cant see the models in the admin panel ]\?

Comment: I am not clear what you are trying to build. why sub apps  ? and there isnt any models inside too... I would suggest you to build seperate apps